# Pth derivative of $2^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the first derivative of $2^x$ is $2x\ln2$, but what is the pattern of it? Like for its pth derivative, what will it be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first derivative is $\ln(2)2^x$. Now $\ln(2)$ is just a constant, so that isn't "seen" by the differentiation, so for the second derivative, you just end up differentiating the same function with a constant in front. So the $n$th derivative is $$\ln(2)^n 2^x$$

**Edit:**
Just because it's fun, let's find the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=2x\ln(x)$:

After the first differentiation we get $\frac{d}{dx}f=2+2\ln(x)$, and after $\frac{d^{n}}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, we have an expression that stays pretty much the same. The first few ones after this are

$$\frac{-1}{x^2},\frac{2}{x^3},\frac{-6}{x^4},\frac{24}{x^5},...$$
Do you see the pattern? It involves $(-1)^k$ which changes the sign every second $k$ and the factorial function, $k!$.

Comment: thank you guys I made a mistake. I thought the first derivative of $2^x$ is $2xlnx$, which is wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since $\log(2)$ is just a constant factor, the pth derivative of $2^x$ is:

$${d^p \over dx^p} 2^x = \log(2)^p 2^x$$

Comment: thank you guys I made a mistake. I thought the first derivative of $2^x$ is $2xlnx$, which is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @J.doe I actually really thought that was a typo and you forgot the power sign